# SQL scalar variable value between and

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005-express

'Names' in table 'Data'

```
"type12pen105A"
"type12pen110A"
"type12pen121B"
```

`Declare @n int;`

```
select Names From Data
where Names ='type12pen'+cast(@n between 100 and 110 as varchar)+'A'
```

My Required out put is

```
"type12pen105A"
"type12pen110A"
```

Comment: -1 Essential information is missing and there seems to be no effort in adjusting the question to add that information. *It always amazes me that people expect us to spend our time answering questions they won't spend their time asking. (George)*

Comment: Sorry the next minute of posting i add some names to that question plz find them.I should have provide more information.I dont want to take much of your time

Comment: Fair enough, I'll remove the downvote after you've edited the question *(the vote is locked now until someone edits the question)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the info you provided, this is ugly but it should work:

```
create table #data
(
    names varchar(50)
)

insert into #data values('type12pen105A')
insert into #data values('type12pen101A')
insert into #data values('type12pen112A')
insert into #data values('type12pen120A')
insert into #data values('type12pen110A')
insert into #data values('type12pen106A')
insert into #data values('type12pen110C')
insert into #data values('type12pen110D')
insert into #data values('type12pen110E')
insert into #data values('type12pen121B')

SELECT Names
FROM #Data
WHERE Names LIKE 'type12pen%' 
AND RIGHT(Names,1) = 'A'
AND replace(replace(names, 'type12pen', ''), 'A', '') BETWEEN 100 AND 110 

drop table #data
```

results:

```
type12pen105A
type12pen101A
type12pen110A
type12pen106A
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Names
FROM Data
WHERE Names LIKE 'type12pen%' 
AND CAST(SUBSTRING(Names,10,3) AS INT) BETWEEN 100 AND 110
AND RIGHT(Names,1) = 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Data table(
  name varchar(32)
)

insert into @Data values('type12pen105A')
insert into @Data values('type12pen110A')
insert into @Data values('type12pen121B')
insert into @Data values('book11jil124C')


select name
from @Data
where cast(substring(name, 10, 3) as int) between 100 and 110
      and name like 'type12pen%'
      and right(name, 1) = 'A'
```

If this is a large table you'd probably be better served by running a process on the data and splitting the different aspects of the product name out into individual fields and querying on those. Using `substring` and `right` means you won't get the benefit of indexes.

Comment: length of numeric is not fixed

Comment: Then you need to modify your question and include more information/examples as to how the name is formatted.